# Wrong value inserted into oauth_access_token table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

I'm setting up Laravel passport in my Laravel application and it is not working as intended when I perform a `Request::create` to `/oauth/token` and Laravel/Passport simply insert my username to the wrong column (`user_id`) in table `oauth_access_tokens`.

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer
>   value: 'admin' for column 'user_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into
>   `oauth_access_tokens` (`id`, `user_id`, `client_id`, `scopes`,
>   `revoked`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `expires_at`) values
>   (720b884efdcc52f13bc1af44703fab477eb37731404104b9da90d9c9e9164809c0fe754b74fc6814,
>   admin, 2, [], 0, 2019-01-04 06:11:32, 2019-01-04 06:11:32, 2019-01-04
>   06:26:32))

For your information my user table does not have typical email/password. This is existing database that I have to construct the model of each table. So basically I have the fields name as below

- us_username
- us_password ~ existing database use md5 to hash it so I make a custom provider
- us_email

and this is how I call the request to `/oauth/token`

```
$data = [
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'client_id' => $client->id,
    'client_secret' => $client->secret,
    'username' => request('us_username'),
    'password' => request('password'),
    'scope' => '',
];

$reqwest = Request::create('/oauth/token', 'POST', $data);
```

I expect it to be insert as usual because I can login as usual through the web interface.

Comment: user_id field expects the value to be inserted be an **integer**. You are inserting value 'admin'

Comment: I am not triggering that call. It's Laravel passport

Answer (score -1):

it look likes $client->id have an 'admin' values..

check why your $client->id values is admin.. maybe it because your input or your user table in database

Comment: I already check it doesnt have admin value. Instead it takes my username value

Comment: have you try this ?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport

Migration Customization
If you are not going to use Passport's default migrations, you should call the  Passport::ignoreMigrations method in the register method of your AppServiceProvider. You may export the default migrations using  php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-migrations.

By default, Passport uses an integer column to store the user_id. If your application uses a different column type to identify users (for example: UUIDs), you should modify the default Passport migrations after publishing them.